# Regex match anything inside the fewest brackets

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to match anything inside the fewest brackets but exclude another brackets inside it.

**Example 1:**

> **String:**
>
> (((1)))(2)
>
> **Result:**
>
> 2

**Example 2:**

> **String:**
>
> (((1)2)3)
>
> **Result:**
>
> 3

**Example 3:**

> **String:**
>
> (1(2(3)))
>
> **Result:**
>
> 1

My regex is:

```
\(((?>[^\(\)]+|(?R))*)\)
```

Unfortunately the result doesn't same.

Comment: I don't know if multiple levels should be possible but for the three above examples where there is always a number in the 'outer level', something easy like (^\((\d)|(\d)\)$) should do the job.

Comment: If the input is `(2((1)2)3)`, what is the expected output?

Comment: If the answer to my above comment is `3`, use `^(\((?>(\d+)|(?1))*\))+$`, the Group 2 will contain the required number.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew if the input is (2((1)2)3), then the output will be 2 and 3. Your regex can solve my 3 conditions above. Can u make a new again for (2((1)2)3)? Thanks!

Comment: I hope the matches will be on differents group for string (2((1)2)3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
(?<!\({2}|\(\d\(|\))(\d)|(\d)(?:\)[^\(\)\d])
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/VMMRP9/6)